# Show value of mysql record in a dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the value from a mysql Db and show the value in a dropdown on a webpage with the correct value selected in the drop down. The value is an integer from 1-10.

I have tried the basic function below but having much luck as the option value says Array for each entry and no selected option is showing. Help please.

```
<select name="Sleeps">
<?php
 $sleeps = $row['Sleeps'];

 $selectedId = array(1, 2, 3);
 $selection = array(
        1 => "1",
        2 => "2",
        3 => "3" );

 foreach($selection as $value){
    $text = $value;
    $selected = '';
    if ($selectedID == $sleeps) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$selectedId.'" selected="'.$selected.'">'.$text.'</option>';
 }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying

```
<option value="'.$selectedId.'" ...>
```

so you're giving the new option the value of an array. I guess there's the problem. Try replacing it with

```
<option value="'.$test.'" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks I used 
<?php
 $sleeps = $row['Sleeps'];

 $selectedId = array(1, 2, 3);
 $selection = array(
        1 => "1",
        2 => "2",
        3 => "3" );

 foreach($selection as $value){
    $text = $value;
    $selected = '';
    if ($selectedID == $sleeps) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$text.'" selected="'.$selected.'">'.$text.'</option>';
 }
?> but get <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option><option value="2" selected="selected">2</option><option value="3" selected="selected">3</option> nearly there but all options have selected="selected"

Comment: the_Seppi Thanks I used

Answer (score 0):

It's doing exactly what you're telling it to essentially. selectedId is not being iterated over in any way, and you're just echoing out the raw value converted to a string.

You'll need a way to access each individual element inside the $selectedId array.

Let's assume that your values in the arrays are always 1,2,3,n

foreach($selection as $value){
    $text = $value;
    $selected = '';
    if ($selectedID == $sleeps) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    echo ''.$text.'';
 }

You need to actually access an index of the array. Since $value will always be a numeric given your loop construct, use it to access an array element, as I've demonstrated above.